# CodeFirst & EDMX in the same application

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, edmx

I have a "legacy" EDMX-based EF model, and a newer CodeFirst model.  I want to be able to incrementally migrate an application from the EDMX to the CF, having both in use at the same time.  Having both models operating in the same AppDomain seems to cause problems. Things work okay with one model until the other model is used, and then everything goes to hell with mapping errors, and remains in that state until the AppDomain is recycled.  For the moment, I have segregated the two models in two different web service applications.  This works fine, but is not ideal.  Is there any way to get them to cooperate in the same AppDomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have "fixed itself" in the last few EF refreshes.  No longer a problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/80ae59ca-0785-44fb-8302-0a0505da2128) on MSDN forums. Hopefully, this information is helpful.

Comment: Interesting, not clear that that is my problem but the workaround seems like it would be worth a shot anyway.  Will follow up, thanks!